# Is it wise to resize my Ubuntu partition without losing data?

Tags: partitioning, 18.04, gparted

I'm dual booting Ubuntu with Windows, but left very little space for windows because I don't use it at all. I now need a little bit of space to run Unity on it so I was thinking of resizing the Ubuntu installation partition and move some space to windows.

I'm fairly sure I can do that while booting Ubuntu from a multiboot USB, but should I do this? Am I risking to lose data on either partition?

Comment: There is always some amount of risk when manipulating partitions. It's like with surgical procedures: there is no surgery without any risk. So, make a backup of the precious data; better safe than sorry. That being said, if you know what you are doing and make a good plan beforehand you will probably not have to restore from said backup.

Comment: It would be wise to backup important data first. There are many things that can go wrong, like a system crash or power outage. If you have enough time, patience and storage space, you can make a `dd` copy of the whole drive to restore the current state in case something goes wrong.

Comment: "but should I do this?"  We can't help you with this question.  But you can always restore a backup. We all make backups of the personal data that's important anyways.